# Enable/disable app from working in background mode

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to enable and disable background mode for my app(android and ios). When background mode is on , app will run in background . When background mode is off, app will not run in background once closed. I see that react native has Appstate .AppState can tell you if the app is in the foreground or background, and notify you when the state changes. But, i want to disable the background mode for application.Any suggestions.Thanks

Comment: What do you mean disable background mode? User cannot perform any actions when app is in background. What do you want to prevent while in background?>

Comment: enable background mode means prevent app from sleep when it goes to background. Disable means opposite of this. While app background mode is disabled, I want to prevent app from tracking movement and location service.

Comment: In cordova ionic framework , there is exact implementation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/.I need same for react native